# Как правильно настроить в PHP Storm и Laravel autocomplete ?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Подскажите как настроить нормально для ларавела пакетов среду разработки для autocompletion ?

_ide_helper.php -> Сгенерирован !

Composer:

```
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4"
   }


    "scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:generate"
    ],
   }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут проблемы нет . 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм а может это поможет Вам.. https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/

Comment: Не везде оно будет работать, так что придется использовать как есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно после установки  ide-helper включить  Fluent методы

1. Скопировать конфиг из папки с проектом хелпера (который в папке vendor) в папку /config вашего фреймворка
2. Изменить настройку

   ```
   'include_fluent' => true,
   ```
3. Запустить команду

   ```
   php artisan ide-helper:generate
   ```

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-generation-for-laravel-fluent-methods